# XML serialize in other format

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a class `Folders`, and I need to serialize this class in a specified format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListFolders  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Folders>
<Id>Dir_1 </Id>
    <Folders>
        <Id>Dir_1_1 </Id>
    </Folders>
    <Folders>
        <Id>Dir_1_2 </Id>
        <Folders>
        <Id>Dir_1_2_1 </Id>
        </Folders>
        <Folders>
        <Id>Dir_1_2_2 </Id>
        </Folders>
    </Folders>
</Folders>
</ListFolders>
```

But after serialize I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ArrayOfFolders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Folders>
    <Id>Dir_1 </Id>
    <ListFolder>
        <Folders>
            <Id>Dir_1_1 </Id>
        </Folders>
        <Folders>
            <Id>Dir_1_2 </Id>
            <ListFolder>
                <Folders>
                    <Id>Dir_1_2_1 </Id>
                </Folders>
                <Folders>
                    <Id>Dir_1_2_2 </Id>
                </Folders>
            </ListFolder>
        </Folders>
    </ListFolder>
    </Folders>
    </ArrayOfFolders>
```

Class `Folder`:

```
public class Folders
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Folders> ListFolder { get; set; }
}
```

How to serialize in correct format?

UPD:

```
using (TextWriter reader = new StreamWriter("data.xml"))
{
    (new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Folders>))).Serialize(reader, data);
}
```

Comment: 1) Identify exactly "which part" is incorrect; and 2) Show the code that serializes it.

Comment: @pst updated. This code isn't my. But I do not understand how to put XML file format to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `XmlElement` attribute to folders list:

```
public class Folders
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Folders")]
    public List<Folders> ListFolder { get; set; }
}
```

Result of serialization `Folders` object will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Folders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>Dir_1</Id>
  <Folders>
    <Id>Dir_1_1</Id>
  </Folders>
  <Folders>
    <Id>Dir_1_2</Id>
    <Folders>
      <Id>Dir_1_2_1</Id>
    </Folders>
    <Folders>
      <Id>Dir_1_2_2</Id>
    </Folders>
  </Folders>
</Folders>
```

BTW `Folders` is a very confusing class name. `Folder` seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: About class name. I agree with you =)